# CMFCToolBar LoadToolBarEx fails for toolbar in CDialogEx

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I'm trying to use `LoadToolBarEx` however it always return `0` and no images appear in the toolbar, however if I use `LoadBitmap` the images load into the toolbar just fine.

My resource image is a PNG 32bit, 32x128 pixels, giving 4 button images.

When using `LoadToolBarEx`:

[image]

When using `LoadBitmap`:

[image]

Contained in `OnInitDialog`:

```
DWORD dwCtrlStyle = TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
DWORD dwStyle = AFX_DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_STYLE;
if (m_ToolBar.CreateEx(this, dwCtrlStyle,
    dwStyle, CRect(1, 1, 1, 1), IDR_TOOLBAR1_PNG))
{
    dwStyle = CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
    m_ToolBar.SetPaneStyle(m_ToolBar.GetPaneStyle() | dwStyle);
}

CMFCToolBarInfo info;

m_ToolBar.SetSizes(CSize(32, 32), CSize(32, 32));
BOOL ret1 = m_ToolBar.LoadToolBarEx(IDR_TOOLBAR1_PNG,info,FALSE); // << THIS FAILS
BOOL ret2 = m_ToolBar.LoadBitmap(IDR_TOOLBAR1_PNG); // << THIS WORKS

CMFCToolBarButton but1(0, 0, L"HELLO", TRUE, 0);
CMFCToolBarButton but2(1, 1, L"HELLO", TRUE, 0);
CMFCToolBarButton but3(2, 2, L"HELLO", TRUE, 0);

but3.SetStyle(but3.m_nStyle | TBBS_DISABLED);
m_ToolBar.InsertButton(but1, 0);
m_ToolBar.InsertButton(but2, 0);
m_ToolBar.InsertButton(but3, 0);
m_ToolBar.SetToolBarBtnText(0, _T("By"));
m_ToolBar.SetToolBarBtnText(1, _T("Your"));
m_ToolBar.SetToolBarBtnText(2, _T("Command"));
m_ToolBar.InsertSeparator(2);

m_ToolBar.SetWindowPos(0, 0, 0, 400, 36, 0, 0);
```

In the `TestDlg.rc` I have:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// PNG
//

IDR_TOOLBAR1_PNG        PNG                  "res\\toolbarNEW.png"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Toolbar
//

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

In `resource.h`:

```
#define IDR_TOOLBAR1_PNG                135
```

What could be causing `LoadToolBarEx` to fail? there is no useful error code to work from, and I've tried various image format combinations so I don't believe it's an issue with the image resource.

Comment: @AdrianMole, Thanks that solved it. In my resource I only had a resource in the PNG section,  the Toolbar section was empty. I hadn't appreciated that there was **both** the **image** for the toolbar and a **toolbar definition** required. (Which is why in my code you can see I was setting up the button layout at runtime) Please can you add this as an answer for me to accept? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LoadToolBarEx()` function expects there to be both a `BITMAP` resource **and** a `TOOLBAR` resource in the ".rc" file, with the two resources sharing the same identifier.

The `BITMAP` resource specifies the bitmap (or other) file from which the button images are loaded and the `TOOLBAR` resource defines the layout of the bar, including the command identifiers for each button.

A typical resource pair for the scenario you describe would be something like the following:

```
IDR_TOOLBAR1_PNG BITMAP "res\\toolbarNEW.png"
IDR_TOOLBAR1_PNG TOOLBAR 16,    16
{
    BUTTON ID_BY       // Each of these ID_xxx values will have been pre-defined...
    BUTTON ID_YOUR
    SEPARATOR          // You can also specify separators herein!
    BUTTON ID_COMMAND
}
```